# How to use macro with Journal Abbreviations?

Tags: macros, bibtex, strings

I have downloaded these macros from [this page](http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs_doc/aas_macros.html). How to use it? I copy the macros to my file macros.tex. Also, I tried to save to a separate file and use \include{}. In both cases, I obtained an error about missing begin{document}.

Comment: Don't use `\include` in the preamble. For `.sty` files use `\usepackage`, for `.tex` files use `\input`. http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty is a `.sty` file so you want to use `\usepackage{aas_macros}` (without file extension!). (If you want to copy the contents of that file into your preamble directly, you probably need `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because of the `@`s: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/35864)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, you're looking to define a number of BibTeX string constants. E.g., if you have a bib entry of type `@article` that has the field

```
   journal = "Astronomical Journal",
```

you'd like to be able to provide this piece of information more succinctly as

```
   journal = aj,
```

i.e., by replacing `"Astronomical Journal"` with `aj`.

If this understanding is correct, I'd like to suggest you create a file called, say, `strings.bib` (the extension `bib` is important) and fill it with lines such as

```
@string{ aj    = "Astronomical Journal" }
@string{ actaa = "Acta Astronomica" }
@string{ araa  = "Annual Review of Astron and Astrophys" }
```

etc.

Next, if your main bib file is called, say, `mybib.bib`, you'd change

```
\bibliography{mybib}
```

to

```
\bibliography{strings,mybib}
```